# Which "math.h" definitions to use to work out maths equations

Tags: c++, math

So I want to work out eqations for things such as the circumfrance of a circle that use things such as pi/π. Looked around and worked out that I need to use

```
 #define _USE_MATH_DEFINES  
 #include "math.h"
 
and

 M_2_PI //presumably
```

But I'm having issues figuring out how to piece this together since the π doesn't exist and you can't do a simple line such as on a calculator. If my radius input is "r" and I try to use something like x = M_2_PI * r; I'll get close results, but close isn't enough in maths.

Are there some instructions or guidelines inside VS to work this better?

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what you mean by "*I'll get close results, but close isn't enough in maths*"?

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion had the right thing of "2*M_PI" in the comments while I was confused and using the wrong one of "M_2_PI" to work out my stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If my radius input is `r` and I try to use something like `x = M_2_PI * r`; I'll get close results, but close isn't enough in maths.

Arithmetic operations on intrinsic number types in pretty-much every non-mathematics programming language will always give you only approximate results - [because that's how integer-types and IEE-754 floating point numbers work. There's no (easy) way around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken/16082201).

(For example, while you can use a Rational-type (such as `boost::rational`][2](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/rational/)) to for *exact* representations of fractional values this approach won't work with  irrational numbers like Pi).

**If you want an** *exact* **answer, then don't use C** - instead use a system designed for high-level mathematics which knows how to represent *exact* values and operate on mathematical expressions rather than approximate numerical values - these systems are [known as a CAS (Computer Algebra System)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) like *Wolfram Mathematica*. Note that you shouldn't confuse CAS systems with non-symbolic [Numerics Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) such as *Matlab* and *Mathcad* (though to an extent almost every mathematics system is capable of both symbolic and numeric operations).

(I credit *Mathematica* for getting me through my A2 Pure and FP courses). TI also sell a line of handheld CAS calculators (I have an nSpire CAS), which are predictably banned for use in most high-level and undergraduate-level exams).